# Can I create a view that needs to calculate its variables using multiple variables from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to learn how to work with databases and php but I have run into some trouble concerning whether I can make a view for what I need or if I would just need to get all the variables into a php function and calculate it there.

Here is the database structure I have decided for the project. (The premise is setup a database and webpage for a truck rental company if it helps.)

```
Vehicles(vehicleId, size, gas)

Price(size, price)

Customer(customerId, firstname, lastname, streetaddress, city, state, zipcode, email, company)

Rental(rentId, customerId, vehicleId, startdate, enddate, tank(0=full positive=number of gallons missing from tank), damage(0=none))
```

So the view in this example I am trying to create would calculate the total cost for each rental for easy display.

The total cost is `price of specific vehicle size * number of days rented (if returned on same day is 1) + (tank * 5) + damage`

The view would also contain the rentalId, and customerId to make it simple to search for total amount spent.

Can I do this in mysql or would it need to be done in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view with all information you need:

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
    SELECT rentId, customerId,
            (price * 
                (CASE DATEDIFF(startdate, enddate)
                      WHEN 0 THEN 1
                      ELSE DATEDIFF(startdate, enddate)
                 ) + (tank * 5) + damage) as totalCost
      FROM Rental r
      JOIN Vehicles v
        ON v.vehicleId = r.vehicleId
      JOIN Price p
        ON p.size = v.size
```

You probably need to review the `CASE DATEDIFF...` to adjust your interval, based on your business rule.

Comment: thank you. Since it's a project that is supposed to be focused more on the database I was hoping to be able to do this in sql.